# How to safely detele a record?

Tags: orm, vlang

**CONTEXT**

I created an app which handles todos. I want to be able to delete todos based on an id I get from the url

```golang
import vweb

struct App {
    vweb.Context
}

[post]
["/todo/:id/delete"]
pub fn (mut app App) delete_todo_response(id string) vweb.Result {
  db := sqlite.open("dist/database.db") or {
    return app.redirect("/todo")
  }

  db.exec_none('DELETE FROM todo WHERE id = $id') // id is not escaped
}

fn main() {
  vweb.run<App>(80)
}
```

**PROBLEM**

As you can see, the id is not escaped. I feel this is not the ideal and secure way to do this.

**QUESTIONS**

- How one can escape values using `exec()`, `exec_one()` or `exec_none()`?
- Is the ORM capable of deleting a record for me based on a struct, like this is possible with select and insert?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no standard way to escape sqlite queries.
However, you can indeed use the ORM.
If you declare your Todo struct, this should do :

```
sql db {
    delete from Todo where id == id
}
```